# Is it able to calculate performance of an application through using it's result JMeter in another machine?

Tags: performance, jmeter, calculation

I have an application running in environment PRODUCT. I want to test it's performance by using JMeter but I can not do it directly to environment PRODUCT, so my idea is test the application in an environment DEV then I can use the result to calculate values in PRODUCT. Can I do that? If it can, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DEV` environment is identical to `PRODUCT` environment - you should be getting the same results.

If `DEV` environment is different - I don't think you will be able to precisely calculate the anticipated performance of the `PRODUCT` environment as there are too many factors to consider and it does not work like: "If my app is serving X requests per second being deployed on a system with Y GB of RAM then it will process X * 2 requests per second on a system with Y * 2 GB of RAM"

[There are several things you still can check on a scaled down environment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test), i.e.

- You can run some form of [integration test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) but under the load, it will allow you to identify any deployment problems i.e. misconfiguration. If there is a problematic long-running slow DB query - it will replicate in production as well
- You can test load allocation and distribution. If your application scales - you can perform [scalability testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing). Load allocation and scaling algorithms will be the same on both environments
- You can perform monitoring of your system using i.e. [PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) to identify the most consumed resource - the situation will be the same in production
- You can run a [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing)  - put your system under a prolonged load. This way you will be able to catch [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- You can use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) while your system is under the load to identify the most resource consuming logic, largest objects, slowest functions, etc.